# Hibernate criteria restriction on multiple criterias

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am writing a Criteria query. My query is on multiple criterias corresponding to tables property and user. It returns the result if prop is 12 or 13 no matter who the user is OR if prop is NULL then user must be loggedInUser.
The Sql query has where condition as follows which returns 4 rows

```
where (property.PROP in (12,13) or (property.PROP is null
                 and user.loggedInUser = 'XYZ'))
```

My criteria

```
Criteria userQuery = session.createCriteria(User.class);
Criteria propertyQuery = userQuery .createCriteria("property");

  Criterion crt = (Criterion) userQuery.add(Restrictions.eq("loggedInUser", userId));

propertyQuery.add(
            Restrictions.or( 
                 Restrictions.in("prop",propList),
                    Restrictions.and(Restrictions.isNull("prop"),crt)
                            )
                 );
```

My issue is that Restrictions.and(criterion,criterion) takes two criterion as parameter. However, the second criterion 'crt' on userQuery is not valid when type casted (Criterion). Hibernate will give error. How can I achieve this functionality in Criteria. or how to write criteria `Restrictions.and(Restrictions.isNull("prop") , userQuery.add(Restrictions.eq("loggedInUser", userId)))`

Comment: join using createAlias wont work?
You might need to look for joins in hibernate criteria.

Comment: Hi sumit badaya creating alias did work. Thanks. I used session.createCriteria(User.class, "user")  and used Restrictions.eq("user.loggedInUser",userId);

Comment: i am glad it helped

Comment: @sumitbadaya Why don't you write it as answer. So that I can accept for others to get if they want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Joins using hibernate criteria as below example code:

```
 List cats = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
     .createAlias("kittens", "kit")
     .add( Restrictions.like("kit.name", "Iz%") )
     .list();
```

***Note: The code above is just an example of how to use Join in hibernate criteria.***